# Brace initialization prevents non-const use of temporary

Tags: c++, temporary, list-initialization

I want to create a temporary copy of a const object and use it in a non-const way:

```
struct S {
    S& f() { return *this; }
};

int main() {
    const S a{};
    S{a}.f(); // Error on this line
    return 0;
}
```

Using msvc (Visual Studio 2017, C++14), I get this error:

> Error C2662   'S &S::f(void)': cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const S' to 'S &'

If I change the brace initialization to classic initialization, it works:

```
S{a}.f(); // Does not work
S(a).f(); // Works
```

Both variants compile fine in gcc. Am I missing something or is this a compiler bug?

Comment: Which version of C++ are you using to compile your code? Assuming C++11

Comment: fyi g++ 5.1.0 compiles ok

Comment: That's [MSVC](http://rextester.com/ROB93477) for you:

Comment: @Elyasin I am compiling this as C++14

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a compiler bug, or the result of a weird optimization, because this  variation of original code that only make ctors and dtor with side effects compiles fine using MSVC:

```
#include <iostream>

struct S {
    S(const S& other) {
        std::cout << "Copy ctor " << &other << " -> " << this << std::endl;
    }
    S() {
        std::cout << "Default ctor " << this << std::endl;
    }
    ~S() {
        std::cout << "Dtor " << this << std::endl;
    }
    S& f() { return *this; }
};

int main() {
    const S a{};
    std::cout << &a << std::endl;
    S{a}.f();
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation is successful and output is:

```
Default ctor 0306FF07
Copy ctor 0306FF07 -> 0306FF06
Dtor 0306FF06
Dtor 0306FF07
```

Answer (score 3):

Seems like another MSVC bug.

`S{a}` is deduced as `const struct S`, and that alone is bug.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template < class T >
std::string type_name()
{
    std::string p = __FUNCSIG__;
    return p.substr( 106, p.length() - 106 - 7 );
}


struct S {
    S& f() { return *this; }
};

int main() {
    const S a{};
    //S{a}.f(); // Error on this line
    std::cout << type_name<decltype(S{a})>() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
const struct S
```

Comment: I would be thankful if you could provide the *link* or the *why* that is a bug.

Comment: @Elyasin It is a bug because there should be no type deduction at all. Direct list initialization does not deduce types.